# How to apply different ResourceDictionary Styles asynchronously every 5 seconds?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mahapps.metro

Below is the Code , in which i want to change the theme color of the MahApps.Metro pakage.

it can be changed by changing the ResourceDictionary Source pack of MahApps.
[/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Accents/Blue.xaml ]

say example its /Blue.xaml now ... we can change colors of the window. to /Red.xaml , /Yellow.xaml etc

So how can i change the color of the window asynchronously in every 5 seconds? is this possible in wpf ?

i am new to wpf and clueless.

```
  <controls:MetroWindow x:Class="NginX.Choose"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:MahApps.Metro.Controls;assembly=MahApps.Metro"
    Title="NginX" Height="350" Width="350" ShowMaxRestoreButton="False">
<Window.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>

         <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Accents/Blue.xaml" />

        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>

</Grid>
</controls:MetroWindow>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can replace the Application's resource dictionary by doing:

```
Application.Current.Resources.Clear()
Application.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Add(new ResourceDictionary()
{
   Source = new Uri("pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Accents/Blue.xaml")
});
```

Put this in a timer and cycle through Red.xaml, Blue.xaml etc